# How to create a vector filled with C-Style function pointers and lambdas(with and without captures)

Tags: c++, lambda, function-pointers, pointer-to-member

Ive been learning about lambdas and function pointers lately and wanted to use them in a simple callback system. 
The map that stores an event and all callbacks that should be called when it gets triggered looks like this:
 `std::unordered_map< sf::Event::EventType , std::vector< Callback > > eventMap;`.

I defined Callback this way 
`typedef void(*Callback)(sf::Event const&);`. My `registerEvent()` function takes an event and a Callback as arguments.
`registerEvent()`can then be called this way:

```cpp
inputHandler.registerEvent(/*Any event type*/, [](sf::Event const&)
{
    //do something
});
```

That works fine but when I want to capture an object I get an compile error saying 
`error: no matching function for call to ‘InputHandler::registerEvent(sf::Event::EventType, Button::Button(ID, Callback, InputHandler&)::<lambda(const sf::Event&)>)’` The code that produces that error is the following:

```cpp
class Button
{
//
public:
    Button(ID id, Callback callback, InputHandler& inputhandler)
    {
        inputhandler.registerEvent(sf::Event::MouseButtonPressed, [this](sf::Event const&)
        {
            {
              getTextureRect();  
            }
        });
    }
};
```

It seems as if the `this` capture is changing the type of the lambda, which makes it incompatible with the `registerEvent()` function. But since lots of different classes should be able to create such lambdas and also lambdas without any capture should be contained in the vector, I don't know how to tell what type the vector should be. I heard of `std::function` but (this may sound silly) I would like to use the C-Style way in order to get a better understanding. I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52190093/10595546) post says something about that but I don't quite understand it that well. I thought about creating two maps, one for all capture-less lambdas and one for the others. Then I could let every class inherit from a base class and make the capture type in the vector a pointer to the base class, though this is pretty complex and adds unnecessary overhead and I don't even know if this would work.
What is the general solution for a situation like this one?

Thanks for all replies and best regards,

Daniel Schreiber Mendes :)

***Edit:***
Callback now looks like this:
`typedef std::function< void(sf::Event const&) > Callback;`
And when I want to use it:

```cpp
//inside the Button Constructor
inputhandler.registerEvent(sf::Event::MouseButtonPressed, Callback([this](sf::Event const& event)
        {
            //memberFunc();
        }));
```

This did not give me an error but behaved in a wrong way. It did execute the lambda, but it didn't change the class in which it was defined. So I added a line in the constructor which just prints the address of the just created object. I am creating only one Button, so there should be only one adress printed. But there were two different. That means when inserting the lambda wrapped in a std::function into a vector, a new Button object gets created. How can that be? An implicit Object creation?

Thanks for your answers :)

Comment: [Simliar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58345417/3871028).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lambdas with captures aren't convertible to function pointers. A plain function pointer hasn't got anywhere to store the state for the lambda's captures.

`std::function` is an object so can store a lambda with or without captures.

If you must use raw function pointers then you need to store a function pointer and a state then pass the state to the function when you call it. e.g.

```
typedef void(*Callback)(sf::Event const&, void* data);
std::unordered_map< sf::Event::EventType , std::vector< std::pair< Callback, void* > > > eventMap;
```

You then need to store your state in an object, store the object somewhere so that it stays alive. Inside your object you need to cast from `void*` back to your state object pointer. If you aren't using a c library that requires plain function pointers then it really is much simpler to just use `std::function` which does all this for you.

Comment: Oh ok thanks. How would the solution with std::function roughly look like?

Comment: Just change your typedef to `typedef std::function<void(sf::Event const&)> Callback;`, `std::function` pretty much behaves like a normal function pointer except you can assign any kind of functor (including lambdas) to them

Comment: Thanks Alan; about "You then need to store your state in an object": Do you mean e.g. `this` as a state? So `void* data` is the argument for the object on which the lambda is called?

Comment: you'd make it whatever you need to use in your function. Just stick to `std::function` unless you really have to do something different

Comment: You should ask a new question (and link back to this one if you like) rather than editing a new question into your existing one